# Create window manager pop only on call answer screen (not always on i.e when back to call answer screen it must be hide)

Tags: android, window-managers

Hi i am create a window manager pop as.

```
package com.appkart.callrecorder.receiver;

import java.util.List;

import android.app.ActivityManager;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.PixelFormat;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.MotionEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.WindowManager;
import android.widget.LinearLayout;

import com.appkart.callrecorder.R;

public class RecordingButtonService extends Service {

    private static final String TAG = RecordingButtonService.class
            .getSimpleName();

    private WindowManager windowManager;
    private LinearLayout chatHead;
    private boolean isRecording;

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        // Not used
        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();

        windowManager = (WindowManager) getSystemService(WINDOW_SERVICE);

        chatHead = new LinearLayout(this);
        chatHead.setBackgroundColor(RecordingButtonService.this.getResources()
                .getColor(R.color.gray));

        final WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams(
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 130,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_PHONE,
                WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE,
                PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT);

        params.gravity = Gravity.TOP | Gravity.CENTER;
        params.x = 0;
        params.y = 0;

        windowManager.addView(chatHead, params);
        chatHead.setOnTouchListener(new View.OnTouchListener() {

            @Override
            public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                    if (!isRecording) {
                        // chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.pause);
                        isRecording = true;
                    } else {
                        // chatHead.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
                        isRecording = false;
                    }
                    return true;
                }
                return false;
            }
        });

    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        return super.onStartCommand(intent, flags, startId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        if (chatHead != null)
            windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
    }
}
```

It works perfectly but my requirement is little bit different.

Requirement

When start outgoing call then we add this pop window on dialer (caller/current) screen but when user pressed back then it continue display pop window while at the time user start using another app or going to home screen.I want to hide this pop window when user leave caller screen and again when user open caller screen, pop window should display.

I know we can remove pop window by

```
windowManager.removeView(chatHead);
```

but i are not getting event when user leave caller screen i.e How to know what is the current screen is display in android app.

Please advice.

Comment: hi do you get any solution